# Tomcat session-timeout does not work after relogging in with same browser session

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, spring-security

I am using Tomcat 7.0.59 with Spring Security 3.2.3.  I am having an issue with the session-timeout not expiring, if I log back into the system after the first expiration with the same browser.

1. login to application
2. let it sit until the session expires - redirected to logout page.
3. logout page has a reference back to the login page. Press it and relogin.
4. let it sit again until the session expires.

After step 4, the session never expires again.

My session information is set to the following in Tomcat web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I removed a setting for the sessionCookiePath="/" in the context.xml and added the session management in the spring configuration.  This gave me a new JSESSIONID for the new login, however, this new one does not expire.  I verified the MaxInactiveInterval is correct for the new session.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: It is actually expiring, however the SessionDestroyed event is never fired for any sessions after the initial session in the browser.  If you open a new browser the sessionDestroyed event fires the first time, but not after that.

Comment: How many SessionDestroyed events do you think you should be getting? Why expect more than a single one?

Comment: I would expect the count of sessionDestroyed calls to match the count of sessionCreated calls.  At this point, sessionCreated is +1 on sessionDestroyed.

Comment: Aah, so the *second* session never dies. I thought you were expecting to get more than one expiration event for the first session. That wasn't clear from your original question.

Comment: Can you verify that the `BackgroundProcessor` thread is still running? There is an issue when that thread dies, no sessions will be expired. The most likely cause of that thread dying is due to some application action during a session event that is catastrophic to the thread.

Comment: One last question: you tagged this question `sprint-security`. Is Spring Security actually involved, here, or is it only Tomcat doing the session-management?